# wordpress htaccess http www redirect to https non-www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

I have read so many posts on this my head is absolutely swimming and nothing I try seems to work properly. My site was http://www I have changed it in the wordpress settings to https://  (non-www) (I have an ssl certificate installed)

I have an existing .htaccess file.
I cant figure out how to adjust my existing .htaccess to redirect all requests to https:// (non-www) Can someone please give me the full code simply of what my htaccess should be ?

This is my existing htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: So what have you tried and what was wrong with it? Please add your attempt(s) to the question, without that we cannot help. We would only repeat all those answers you claimed not working for you.

Comment: Also a general remark: you should prefer to place such rules in the general hosts configuration. That way things are less complex, more robust and you even speed up your http server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this post](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/) you can change your `.httaccess` file to redirect:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com
```

using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

simply add this code after `#end wordpress` in your `.htaccess` file.

after saving the `.htaccess` file remember to save your permalink structure in `settings->permalink`.

Comment: Thanks - I added that after #end wordress and before the # php line but when I go to a sub page in my navigation menu links such as 
https://example.com/dog-breeds-f-j/  
I get a 404 error for that page :

Not Found
The requested URL /dog-breeds-f-j/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: go to `settings->permalink` and save the page, actually you need to save your permalink structure once more.

Comment: Thanks -that did it.  The pieces I was missing was putting it AFTER # end wordpress, and re-saving the permalink structure.  Thanks so much !